# Azure Data factory : Select all the table from source where date lower than pipline date

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am learing Azure Data Factory, I would like to know to upload all the table from source with Azure Data factory using sql query

thanks in advance [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not upload all the tables from source with Azure Data factory using sql query. Even in the database, we can't not achieve that for now. It needs import the schema and data in Data Factory before data copying.

In Copy active tool, it actually using an for each active to copy all the tables from the source.

If you want to filter the data in a specified table, you could run the query in your screenshot with the parameter.

And for the question in your title, what's the meaning of "date lower than pipeline date"? We can't understand that. If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given the absence of a specific question, [here is a tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool) for using the Copy Data tool in ADF which you are referencing.